# Open source HTML/CSS/JAVA code under GPLv3 license - implication if used for public company website?

Tags: gpl-3, license-recommendation, website

I would like to use some open source HTML/CSS/JAVA code under a GPLv3 license to feed into my company website (start up).
I am not 100% clear whether I can use the open source code or at which stage I need to pay for a corporate license.

(1) Open source GPLv3 license - is my understanding correct that the website, which has information about the company and may go as far as letting customers book appointments but is not directly a product which is sold is not classified as commercial and as long as I make it clear in the code where the code is from, what changes I have made and publish my code under the same license, then I am legally fine to use the code free of charge?

(2) In which case would I need to pay for a corporate license?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been asked before on the site. See also this FAQ: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#UnreleasedMods

Comment: Probably your second question about a "corporate license" is outside of the scope of Open Source. It depends on who defines that license, what your obligations are, if you operate under such a license.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.